# Sql Server Full Text Search matching some words

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm using Sql Server Full Text Search and I need to search a list of job titles based on a long description. And I need to get the ones that have more word matches. For example, if a title has 2 words in common with the description and there's another one with 3 words in common, I prefer the one with 3 words (it could be even better if I can get a percentage of match, meaning matched words over total word count).

I know that normally the search is done over the long description but I want to try the opposite direction.

This is what I have for the moment:

```
SELECT title, t.rank
FROM JobTitle(NOLOCK) ja
inner join containstable(JobTitle, title, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "client") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "service")') as t ON ja.JobTitleId=t.[Key]
order by 1
```

**EDIT**

This is very useful and I hope it helps others:

```
select top 100 Title, SUM(occurrence_count) AS MatchedWordsCount, COUNT(*) AS MatchedUniqueWordsCount
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document
( 
    5,     693577509 
)
inner join JobTitle cjt ON document_id=cjt.JobtitleId
where display_term='client' or display_term='service'
group by Title
order by 3 desc, 2 desc
```

Comment: The full text engine will generally give a higher rank to the results that match more words (I am oversimplifying because the matching algorithm is much more complex than that). You should see this if you `order by t.rank desc`. Do you intend to ignore these ranks and compute your own rank solely based on the # of words in common? Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'opposite direction'?

Comment: The rank is not so useful when you use the AND operator, it gets almost the same ranking for all the rows and some rows have a higher ranking but the results are not better than the others. I think that I could use the OR operator and count words to improve the results. When I say the opposite direction it means that I use the long description to search titles that have shorter descriptions. Normally you would you use a few words to search long descriptions.